# Wrap L-System/Fractals around a Sphere

Tags: animation-nodes, procedural

How would I take an L-System structure similar to this image
[image]

And wrap that structure seamlessly around a sphere like this: [image]

It has to be a legitimate L-system, not faked or similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach using Alessandro Zomparelli's [Tissue](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue/wiki) Add-on, rather than Animation Nodes, roughly following his examples presented [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-fNCdjNztk) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Liv--XSaCg).

- Create a Unit Plane, with its own origin at its minimum XY, placed at the World 0.
- Add a single vertex to the object at its center.
- Place the 3D cursor at the center of the sphere you wish to cover, and set the transformation pivot to it.
- Duplicate the plane & vertex, using only rotations about the 3D cursor to place it. (Planes will be the growth nodes) - <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the first central vertex and snap to other vertices in the now multi-plane object to create branches.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> merge vertices by proximity, and delete planes you do not wish to be growth nodes.
- When done, this is your Base object.  <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> make an instance of it to be the Component.

[image]

(The physical sphere is just there for illustration)

- In the Tissue panel, hit 'Tessellate'
- In the Tessalations Data region, 'Tissue' panel, you will be able to adjust the settings:

[image]

If the coordinates have been set correctly, you should wind up with something like the left example below. Delete faces and remove doubles again to get the one on the right.

[image]

Which gives you a spherical L-system topology to treat as you wish.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a great solution. thank you!